# EC2 snapshot stays in "deleting" state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have an issue with importing EC2 snapshots to create an AMI. During our build process we use [EC2:ImportSnapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ImportSnapshot.html). This has worked fine for months and it still works fine in the `us-east-1` region. In the `us-east-2` region we noticed that some import tasks were active for several days. Normally, these imports complete within 5-20 minutes.

We tried to delete these imports by running [EC2:CancelImportTask](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CancelImportTask.html), but now the import tasks are in the `deleting` state for days.

When I run `aws ec2 --region us-east-2 describe-import-snapshot-tasks | jq '.ImportSnapshotTasks[] | select(.SnapshotTaskDetail.Status=="deleting") | .ImportTaskId'`, it shows 16 import tasks that are in the `deleting` state. How can I make sure they actually get cleaned up?

There is a limit of 20 import tasks, so we cannot upload a bunch of AMIs anymore. AWS technical support is not available (it's at a paid plan), but I guess it's something on their end. What are my options?

Comment: You can always join Support and then cancel Support. Explain to them that it's an AWS problem and they might even refund the (short-term) support costs.